# SSL tunnel through proxy server

Tags: openssl

Basically I want to create SSL tunnel through proxy server programatically. I am using oppnssl to create ssl tunnel, which I could create but not sure how I can create a tunnel through proxy server.

Answer (score 1):

See 5.2 (Requesting a tunnel with CONNECT) in [RFC2817](http://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2817.html).